# How to write smart card with pyscard

Tags: python, smartcard

I'm using reader/writer acr38f and my smart card is SLE4418. How do I read and write text to my smart card?

For example: `Hello World!`

> apdu = [0XFF, 0X20,0x00,0x00,0x02, 0x00, 0x00]
>
> response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit( apdu )
>
> ```
> apdu = [0XFF,0xA4,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x05]
> response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit( apdu )
>
>
>
>
> apdu = [0XFF,0XB2,0X00,0xA7,0X09]
> response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit( apdu )
> print response
>
>
> apdu = [0XFF, 0XD0,0x00,0xA7,0x09,0xA7,0x02,0xA7,0x02,0xA7,0x02,0xA7,0x02,0xA7] 
> response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit( apdu )
> ```

card response :

```
connecting to ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR 3B 04 92 23 10 91
>  FF 20 00 00 02 00 00
<  00 00 00 90 0 
>  FF A4 00 00 01 05
<  []  90 0 
>  FF B2 00 A7 09
<  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 90 0 
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
>  FF D0 00 A7 09 A7 02 A7 02 A7 02 A7 02 A7
<  []  90 0
```

Comment: It's not a final answer but you can try to grok your reader's [manual](http://www.smartcardreader.ru/upload/catalog/items/docs/doc5155.pdf), then use [PyUSB](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyusb/) to work with it...

Comment: Do you want to read/write a text to your smart-card memory? What do you mean under "read and write my smart card to text"?

Comment: @sasha yes i want write a memory. @pill i don't know how to using pyusb...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not have the hardware to test this, but this should get you going:

Communicating with smart cards involves sending APDU *(Smart Card application protocol data unit)* commands and receiving APDU responses.

Command APDUs are sent through the reader/write (your ACR38F) and consists of a 4-byte header followed by data (and info about the data size and response size)

```
Field    Len Description
--------------------------------------------
CLA     (1) Instruction Class
INS     (1) Instruction Code
P1-P2   (2) Instruction Parameters
Lc  (0,1,3) Number of data bytes to follow
DATA    (*) Data to be transmitted
Le    (0-3) Maximum response bytes
```

The response consists of:

```
Field    Len Description
--------------------------------------------
DATA    (*) Data to be transmitted
SW1-SW2 (2) Command status
```

In the case of the [SLE4418, in order to write data,](http://www.cardcontact.de/download/eco5000/README.html) the values should be as follows:

- CLA = 00
- INS = D6
- P1 = MSB of memory address offset to store bytes
- P2 = LSB of memory address offset to store bytes
- Lc = length of bytes to store
- DATA = data to store
- Le = (empty)

So therefore in code:

```
WRITE = [0x00, 0xD6]
STARTMSB = [0x00] #change to where on the card you would like to write
STARTLSB = [0x00] #same here
MEM_L = [0x01]
DATA = [0x01]

cardservice.connection.connect()
apdu = READ + STARTMSB + STARTLSB + MEM_L + DATA
response1, sw1, sw2 = self.cardservice.connection.transmit( apdu )
```

Other relevant info:

- http://www.belelectro-m.by/docs/doc3723.pdf
- http://www.youcard.de/datenblaetter/chipkarten/DB%20SLE441828.pdf