# Read security memory Command for sle5542 smart card

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I'm not kidding you when i tell you I've been looking for days for the APDU commands for
the sle5542 smart card.
I have read the datasheet...and I still cant figure it out. 
The APDU  RESET command is: FF A4 00 00 01 06
The command I'm looking for is : Read security memory

The command should look something all the same format as the "reset" command.....I'm aqssuming.

I'm not sure  why the codes are so hard to locate.

If you could provide me with the command, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [working with IC card reader and SLE5528 smart card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145103/working-with-ic-card-reader-and-sle5528-smart-card)

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110148/i-cant-find-apdu-commands-for-sle5542), or even duplicate.