# Smart card Access Speed

Tags: performance, smartcard, apdu, read-data

Today here many Smart card available but some smart card take 4-5 second for Access data use command APDUs like i am use SLE 4442 its take 5 second to access.
I need those Smart card which is access in 1 second no more time take and one thing more card work with java and i am use ACR-38 Smart Card Reader and Writer

```
         byte[] cmdApduPutCardUid = new byte[]{(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xD0,  (byte)0x40,(byte)0x00,  (byte)4,(byte)6,(byte)2,(byte)6,(byte)2};
```

and also suggest the cmdApduPutCardUid command of these cards

Thanks

Comment: You already asked for APDUs  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850578/read-write-data-in-sle4442-smart-card-with-java-commandapdu).

Comment: @guidot please help me if you have code to write data in these cards i am use ACR38U-I1 reader writer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SLE4442 is a memory card, no smart card. It does not understand any APDU, the translation to the communication protocol is done by the reader, see (among many similar ones) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110148/i-cant-find-apdu-commands-for-sle5542/18060416#18060416). Trying some different readers to find a faster one is surely an option. But I would definitely recommend to use a real smart card, where 115 kBit/s are easily reached.

Comment: How i am read and write data in this memory card if pin is by default.

Comment: Please help me if you have java code for this SLE4442       Thanks

Comment: i am work on this problem from last year but its not solve

Comment: @RubyBhullar: As explained, the reader (or its driver) implements the APDUs, so look into its manual - I have not yet seen an ACS-38 and definitely not programmed for it. The default PIN is typically 0000; look into the data sheet of your chip for a possibly different value, and into the reader manual for the format of PIN verification command.  If the reading already works (since it can be measured), verify and write should be reached easily.

Comment: if i am change the card type means if i am use other card which is support ACS-38 and Java So please Suggest me what card type i am use For example SLE5528 etc

Comment: i am tell you what i want

Comment: i am use id card which contain chip where i am use java write the employee id number inside chip and read it many time

Comment: please help me if you have code to write data in these cards i am use ACR38U-I1 reader writer

Comment: @RubyBhullar: Stack Overflow is a forum for asking questions to solve the problems yourself. I already stated that I don't have seen the reader, so further comments won't help.

Comment: Thanks For reply and in future if you find the solution then tell me